# c++ find_if an element in struct returning only first element

Tags: c++

I want to return the element in `struct` that has the `a=5`. However, it cannot find it using `find_if`. The value the `(*it).a` returns is always the first element which is 0. Below is the code.

```
struct vect_map {
    int a;
    int b;
};
int main () {

    int iteration = 20000;
    vector< vect_map > vect;
    vect.reserve( iteration );
    for( auto i=0; i<iteration; ++i) {
        if( i==iteration-200 ) {
            vect[i].a = 5; 
            vect[i].b = 100;
        }
        else {
            vect[i].a = i; 
            vect[i].b = 1;
        }
    }
    int n=5;
    auto it = find_if( begin( vect ), end( vect ), [&n] (const vect_map &e) { return e.a==n; } );
    if( it!=vect.end() ) {
        cout << (*it).a << endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vect[i]` has undefined behaviour, because `i` is not less than `vect.size()`.

You need to give your vector the correct size:

```
vect.resize(iteration);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your loop that populates the `vector` is incorrect: `reserve(n)` does not create a vector of the desired length, only allows you to `push_back` without reallocation up to the specified limit.

You can fix this problem either by pushing back the desired elements as you go, or by making an array of 2000 items using the appropriate constructor:

```
const int iteration = 20000;
vector< vect_map > vect(iteration);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/n5yuay)